# print ajax output in div

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Please help me, my ajax don't print any output but when i used alert() to print the output it shows the output.

```
  $(".grp-ans").each(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show-answer.php',
            data: { 
               'p_id': $(this).attr('id')
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(this).text(data);
            },error: function(msg){
                $(this).text("error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Can you show the ajax output?

Comment: the out is just a simple text  like "Lester"

Comment: the `this` refers to the function itself. you may want to use fat arrow instead. Convert `function(e)` to ` (e) => ` Or maybe just use `$(e.target).text(data)` if that is the event

Comment: e is the numerical index afaik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess i know what your problem is here: Your reference to `this` in the ajax-callback is changed. Try to bind the callbacks like this:

```
  $(".grp-ans").each(function(e){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'show-answer.php',
            data: { 
               'p_id': $(this).attr('id')
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(this).text(data);
            }.bind(this),error: function(msg){
                $(this).text("error");
            }.bind(this)
        });
    });
```